# How to visualize the ansible-playbook run command in a web UI format

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible yaml file and mentioned all the hosts in a different file. When I run a playbook in cli, I would like to visualize in which of the hosts, the ansible play is successful and in which of the hosts the play is unsuccessful in a web UI. Are there any tools/apps that can solves this issue.

Comment: Are you using a specific stdout callback plugin? (i.e. what is the result of `ansible-config dump | grep DEFAULT_STDOUT_CALLBACK`?) The `default` plugin gives a play recap with a list of targeted servers and their ok/changed/unreachable/failed/skipped/rescued/ignored tasks.

Comment: DEFAULT_STDOUT_CALLBACK(default) = default

Comment: Well then you should pretty much have what you are asking for at the end of you cli output.

Comment: My requirement is that I would like to visualize all the host details and the tasks where it was successful and  the tasks where the tasks has a failure in a web ui instead of opening ansible server

Comment: Redirect the output to a file and show the file. But here we looped: you basically reinvented a weak version of tower/awx

Comment: Alternatively, you can write a callback plug-in that can create the needed file for you or see if one already exists that feats your needs.

Comment: I have a Bamboo plan which runs the ansible playbook whenever there was an update to the ansible playbook, to monitor the host details for the tasks we need an web UI to monitor it instantly without logging into any server. Please let me know the best possible way to approach this

Comment: I already did that in my previous comments.

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks for the information. I am returning the ansible output in Json format, using promethues and Grafana I was able to check the status of Ansible playbooks in Grafana instantly

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for [Ansible Tower](https://www.ansible.com/products/tower) (paid) or [AWX](https://github.com/ansible/awx) (free). These two are the same thing actually (AWX is an upstream branch of Tower). With both you can run playbooks using web UI and there is some indication if there were failed hosts.

Comment: I have looked into Ansible tower, not sure on how to configure it to show the hosts details (success or failure)  when I run ansible-playbook command in cli

Comment: @Jayachandra Sorry, that won't work with cli. Only if you run it with Tower.